# Kotlin, Build failed with an exception (no error message)

Tags: android, kotlin

Unfortunately this is another 'Build failed with an exception (no error message)' challenge.

I've been at this for sometime and cannot find much to pin point or resolve the issue from the build output (shortened version below).

After reviewing similar stack questions with the same or a similar build output Im still having no luck. I've tried, analysing/inspecting the code and reviewing the errors, updated to the latest stable versions of anything that wasn’t, read and reread code for several hours without spotting any issues.

Execution failed for task ':app:data:kaptDebugKotlin'.

From the above, there is obviously something not working with the app:data module. This module contains the data component of the project and is mostly room and database code.

Any direction or troubleshooting tips would be fantastic!

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:data:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:data:kaptDebugKotlin'
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first(_Collections.kt:212)
    at androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor.processRelationField$lambda-43$findAndValidateJunctionColumn(PojoProcessor.kt:554)
    at androidx.room.processor.PojoProcessor.processRelationField(PojoProcessor.kt:574)
```

There is a lot more build output text, however limited in the total size I can drop in.

Comment: Hard to help you without the source code. Have you tried running with --info or --scan as the error message suggested?

Comment: thanks @xjcl 
The output of the stacktrace, info, degbug and scan, are all essentially the same.  It runs through a series of tasks for this and other modules that complete successfully. Then it stops here. Each time the message and available information is the same.  
Using analyse>Inspect code no room based errors are shown.  Sorry I cant be more specific as Im not sure the cause. ~400 files in the data module and I can potentially reduce this to about 30 (modified in the last week) but as other modules also modified draw from this and maybe causing the issue.

Comment: Well I guess I can't help much, other than saying it's probably trying to process some function annotation so I would try commenting them out to narrow down the issue (maybe search for an `@` sign in the recent commits). Speaking of which, you can also do binary search over the recent commits to quickly identify at which point the project stopped being able to build. Good luck.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue!  I will post anything if I find an answer for you :)

Comment: I noticed I had an issue with mismatched key names across classes.  Check that the column names match across junction tables and other classes.  Best of luck!